# Any door villager can't open

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am making a jail for villagers but all of them can open the door and be free.

Is there any door a villager can't open?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. In fact, villagers can *only* open wooden doors.

Villagers can't open fence gates or trap doors, nor can they use buttons or levers, allowing you to use iron doors, iron trapdoors, or just about any redstone-based door mechanism without them being able to escape.

Comment: Is this answer still valid, with current Minecraft versions? Yesterday I saw a villager exit an iron door which could only be opened with a wooden button. It was on Bedrock edition (Xbox one), single player survival mode, and I'm pretty sure about the door - I built it, no pressure plates or anything other than the button, and no mobs in the room other than 2 villagers. It may have been a glitch though, I had just used that same door... I heard it close, and then 5 seconds later it reopened for the villager and closed again. Weird...

Answer (score 0):

Villagers can in fact open iron doors something alot of people overlook if there is no pressure plate or lever etc. Then will be able to open and close the door and in some cases lock you out of your house. I've had this happen in my current survival world. I've even had them open the iron door when there is a lever and a pressure plate too but I think that's more of a bug with the pressure plate on the other side of my doors than it is with the villagers ability to open it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use glass and sticky pistons. Just stick the sticky pistons in the wall facing you and put a button on the same wall, then make a redstone wire leading to the two sticky pistons. You could put another button and do the same thing with the inside so that you don't get stuck in there either.

Answer (score -1):

that was fixed in the newer updates of bedrock and java i have never had a villager open a iron door in vanilla minecraft but in the furnicraft addon for minecraft bedrock robert gomes screwed with the code allowing villagers to open iron doors that is the only instance that thats happened to me but it was fixed in the later versions of minecraft